# Linking an unknown dll

Tags: dll, dllimport, loadlibrary

I've got this dll (called unknown.dll) from which i only know what Ghidra told me. I'm using LoadLibraryW to load it, but (in x86) it throws me the error 126. However, in 64x it gives me the error 193, so i don't think that the problem is that my program can't find my dll...
Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

typedef int(__cdecl* FunctionIWant)();

int main()
{
HMODULE hmod = LoadLibraryW(L"C:\\unknown.dll");

if (hmod != NULL)
{
    ...
}

else
    std::cout << GetLastError();

return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

126 is `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`. Either your DLL can't be found, or more likely one if it's dependencies can't be found.

193 is `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`. This is because you can't mix 32 and 64 bit DLLs.

The fact that you get `ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT` when you run under 64 bit tells you that your DLL is found. Therefore we can conclude that its dependencies are not present.

Consult the documentation to discover what dependencies are required.

Comment: The dll itself  was throwing this error. I used "SetDllDirectory" to point to its original location and it worked! Thanks